# Yield several states in a row but not all are received by the BlocBuilder

Tags: flutter, dart, stream, bloc

I have a BLoC in my app. A View is build upon this BLoC. The View has two main states: let's call them `IsGreen` and `IsRed`. Everytime the user taps on a button, the BLoC should switch to another state. So far so fine.

Now I need the the View to display a notification based on a in-between-state. This special state is called `IsBlue`. If the BLoC switchs from the red state to the green one. During the switch a method is called which can throw an exception or return a result. If the exception is thrown, a notification should be displayed. If the result is valid, show the result.

My `mapEventToState` looks as follows:

```dart
@override
Stream<MyState> mapEventToState(MyEvent event) async* {
  switch(event) {
    case MyEvent.goRed:
      yield IsGreen();
      break;
    case MyEvent.goGreen:
      yield* doSomeStuff();
      break;
  }
}

Stream<MyState> doSomeStuff() async* {
  try {
    String result = doSomething();
    yield IsBlue(result);
  } on MyException {
    yield IsException();
  }
  yield IsGreen();
}
```

With some logging I found out that the states are properly yielded but the BlocBuilder is not receiving them all. Only the `IsGreen` and the `IsRed` events are received. `IsBlue` and `IsException` are missed. I don't undestand why. Am I not allowed to send multiple States directly after another?

Does anyone know how often and how fast I can yield state changes?

Comment: It yields either blue or exception but then it yileds green. The last state is always green so yielding other 2 states are obselete. You can't yield 2 states at the same time, the first state will be overriden in microseconds.

Comment: Ah ok. So the Builder never receives the blue state or the exception as it always gets directly overridden by the green state. How can I avoid that?

Comment: Nothing is overriden - states emitted as expected IsBlue, IsGreen or IsException,IsGreen. If IsBlue is never builded by BlocBuilder it's mean that it is equal to previous emitted state and will be filtered. Bloc does filtering of conseqent equal states. You need to check your states implementation of equal&hashcode

Comment: But my states are different classes. That's why I don't understand why the isBlue and isException are never build.

Comment: How did you confirm they never built?  If you wan't to be sure you might write test with bloc_test package to confirm bloc emits states as you intended. Most simpliest way just put `print(state)` in BlocBuilder

Comment: Every time the builder is triggered, the first thing it does, is printing the new status to the console. Just what you suggest. And isBlue or isException never get printed...

Comment: Please extract minimal reproducable example, there is something we can't observe problem in current code snippet